# Different behavior after page is reloaded (app is in production mode, made by react and express)

Tags: reactjs, express, build, react-router

Everything works fine in development mode. At first look app is identical in build mode (I am using express for server side). But when I try to refresh my page (url contains params) I receive
only

```json
{
surveyString: "[{"type":"radiogroup","name":"Favorite Character?","title":"Favorite Character?","isRequired":true,"colCount":1,"choices":["Walt","Hank","Jesse","Mike"]},{"type":"radiogroup","name":"Favorite Actor?","title":"Favorite Actor?","isRequired":true,"colCount":1,"choices":["Aaron Paul","Bryan Cranston","Jonathan Banks"]}]",
surveyTitle: "Breaking Bad Survey"
}
```

which is response send from server, which of course i want, but somehow app doesn't incorporate it.

Error which i receive in Chrome is

> Not allowed to load local resource: view-source

In Firefox error looks somehow different

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource a ...resource link...

Through these errors I acknowledged about Content Security Policy, some basic method how express package works to overcome it and so on... But that is different story and I hope I will solve problem on react side.

I am optimist because I have identical behavior from a href links on other page. When I replace aHref with LinkTo app works as excepted.

I click on link and on a new page everything is ok, until I make refresh.

link is to github page:
[component which not survives refresh](https://github.com/NikolaGolubovic/front-survey/blob/master/src/components/SingleSurvey.js)

```js
function SingleSurvey(props) {
  const [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);
  const [voted, setVoted] = useState(false);
  const [json, setJson] = useState({});
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [resultsDisplay, setResultsDisplay] = useState(false);

  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    surveyServices.getSingle(id).then((res) => {
      const stringQuestions = JSON.parse(res.surveyString);
      setJson({ questions: stringQuestions });
      setTitle(res.surveyTitle);
    });
  }, [id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkItem = window.localStorage.getItem(`chartVoted-${id}`);
    if (checkItem) {
      setVoted(true);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  function onComplete(result) {
    surveyServices.updateVotes({
      data: result.data,
      id,
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem(`chartVoted-${id}`, true);
    setComplete(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.reload();
    }, 1100);
  }
  return (
    <main className="survey-page">
      {complete && <p className="survey-finished"></p>}
      {!voted ? (
        <>
          <Survey.Survey
            json={json}
            showCompletePage={false}
            onComplete={(result) => onComplete(result)}
          />
          <div className="show-results">
            <button
              className="btn-results"
              onClick={() => setResultsDisplay(!resultsDisplay)}
            >
              {resultsDisplay ? "Hide Charts" : "Show Charts"}
            </button>
            <div
              className="visible-results"
              style={{ display: resultsDisplay ? "" : "none" }}
            >
              <Result id={id} title={title} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="just-results">
          <Result id={id} title={title} />
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  );
}
export default SingleSurvey;
```

[switch routes settings](https://github.com/NikolaGolubovic/front-survey/blob/master/src/App.js)

```js
<Router>
      <Notification />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/api/survey/single/:id" component={SingleSurvey} />
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

ReactDOM render, I am using basic redux

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>,
```

[express](https://github.com/NikolaGolubovic/happysurvey/blob/master/app.js)

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.use("/api/survey", surveyController);
app.use("/api/users", usersController);
app.use("/api/login", loginController);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
  });
});
```

If you want to see directly problem [app is uploaded on heroku](https://veryhappysurvey.herokuapp.com/).

I hope I don't miss any valuable information. Anyone has idea how to fix unbelievably annoying problem?

Comment: Why are you using nested app.get calls?

Comment: I can't recreate the error, what are the exact steps that cause the error?

Comment: @AlexMckay I use nested calls because i followed [create-react-app doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing). I also tried no nested solution and result was the same. To recreate error you need to go to single survey from my homepage and refresh page or you can simply [click here](https://veryhappysurvey.herokuapp.com/api/survey/single/b3317a3a-1e85-4aa3-9c8b-88477163bd72).

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused and consequently overloaded your API routes and your client side routes.

When web browsers go to a website they are making GET requests, exactly the same as how you interact with your express server.

Your issue here is you are accidentally making a get request to your server by redirecting your users to your server endpoint which makes a GET request to your server.

**What is happening**

- Url change triggered by a `Link` component (not in the code you've provided
- React Router matches the URL without triggering an API request (this is how single page web app work)
  `<Route exact path="/api/survey/single/:id" component={SingleSurvey} />`
- On page refresh Express matches the URL and returns the API response instead of the index.html
  `app.use("/api/survey", surveyController);`

**Solution**

- Change your client-side paths to something like: `/client/survey`

Comment: Alex, you were more than helpful. With your suggestion and little more work I somehow fixed problem. Thank you, man.

Answer (score 0):

Following Alex Mckay's answer I change route location

```js
 <Route
    exact
    path="/client/survey/single/:id"
    component={SingleSurvey}
  />
```

And than fix content security policy error on my server side.
It is whole new area for me so I follow errors in my console and fix it one by one.
It is highly intuitive process with [helmet-csp] package.

```js
app.use(
  csp({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      fontSrc: ["https://fonts.googleapis.com/", "https://fonts.gstatic.com"],
      connectSrc: ["'self'", "http://localhost:3005"],
      styleSrc: [
        "'self'",
        "'unsafe-inline'",
        "https://surveyjs.azureedge.net/1.8.0/modern.css",
        "https://fonts.googleapis.com",
        "'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='",
        "'sha256-OTeu7NEHDo6qutIWo0F2TmYrDhsKWCzrUgGoxxHGJ8o='",
      ],
      imgSrc: ["'self'", "http://localhost:3005"],
      scriptSrc: [
        "'self'",
        "unsafe-inline",
        "'sha256-eE1k/Cs1U0Li9/ihPPQ7jKIGDvR8fYw65VJw+txfifw='",
      ],
      objectSrc: ["'none'"],
      upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
    },
    reportOnly: false,
  })
);
```

Also I removed inline style from one of my component because component behaved strange

```js
<>
          <Survey.Survey
            json={json}
            showCompletePage={false}
            onComplete={(result) => onComplete(result)}
          />
          <div className="show-results">
            <button
              className="btn-results"
              onClick={() => setResultsDisplay(!resultsDisplay)}
            >
              {resultsDisplay ? "Hide Charts" : "Show Charts"}
            </button>
            {resultsDisplay && (
              <div>
                <Result id={id} title={title} />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
</>
```

And it works.